# How to search for curly quotes on an StackExchange site?

Tags: support, search

Assume that I want to compare the relative usage/popularity of `“` vs `"` on an SE site. I expect ELL and ELU to be curly-dominant, StackOverflow to be straight-dominant, but I am not so sure about the other sites, especially the science sites.

I can easily search for the [straight quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22). But, every time I type type the smart quote and press Enter, the search string is replaced by `"“"` and the search returns [zero results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9C) (even when I know of posts on that site which have that curly quote in them). For example [a search](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9C) on Chem.SE results zero results, yet there are several posts like [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/62934/5026), which use the curly quotes.

Is this the expected result? Why is the search not working correctly here?

Comment: @rene Ok thanks. With your SEDE query I managed to change it slightly to suit my purpose. Link - http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/edit/812743